# Win API (printers) - winspool.h

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, winapi, visual-c++, printing

Im' using the win api and some funcions from winspool.h to work with my printers. Functions like OpenPrinter/StartDoc/ etc...

I'm able to print and everything looks fine. The only problem, or issue i can't addrress is about margins.
My printer seems to add some weird bottom margin and some images/text that are close to bottom are cutted off.
I want to remove this margin, and from other programs i can use the print setup to remove them. 
but i can't find out how to do it from my code. Something like:

```
dc->margin = &rect;

or:
dc->margin->bottom_margin = 0;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Most printers cannot print to the very edge of the paper, and the margins are usually bigger at the top and bottom (in the direction of the paper feed).  The area you can print to is called the [printable area](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144877%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Have you tried setting the margins to zero in another application and printing something?  Does anything appear in the areas your application can't print in?

Answer (score 0):

You can get printer margins. Look for PHYSICALOFFSETX and PHYSICALOFFSETY.
Usually people get it and after they do minus from margins what they need.

But window program for printing pictures can print without any margins.
I couldn't find information how  it does it. I think it's undocumented feature.